# Activity vs AppCompatActivity: Difference in UI

Tags: android, android-activity, appcompatactivity

I'm developing an Android app. In some cases I used an Activity and in others, an AppCompatActivity. Although I noticed one thing:

Lets take this class for instance:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setTheme( android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the output is the desired one: 
[image]

When I change the extended class from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` the output changes to:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I think it is or a bug or the Android theme decided to keep the dialog white also for the dark theme. The problem is the attribute `colorBackground` it seems NOT to be on `background_material_dark` which points to `@color/material_grey_850`.

Here is my solution:
Add to your color the folloging:

```
<color name="background_material_dark_public">@color/material_grey_850</color>
```

and set it. In my case:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    activity.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
    int color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(activity.getResources(), R.color.background_material_dark_public, null); //without theme
    activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AppCompatActivity - Provides Material color themes, widget tinting, and app bar support to earlier devices. Use of this class requires that you use Theme.AppCompat themes for consistent visual presentation.

For more info look into this url : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features#v7-appcompat

Simply : AppCompact activity uses Theme that why its changing

Activity wont have action bar where as AppCompactActivity will have action bar by default.

Comment: ...but I'm setting the theme by code. Isn't it the same regarding the colors?

Comment: can you share the snippet the code you wrote(setting the theme)